# Mixing two audio files in two channels using tone.js in angular

Tags: angular, web-audio-api, tone.js

I have two audio files(music and voice) and I want to mix these together using tone.js channel component. Currently I am able to play two files simultaneously together as below

```
play()
{
   var soundSamples = new ToneAudioBuffers({
    Music: "assets/audio/music.mp3",
    Voice: "assets/audio/voice.mp3",
  }, () => {
    const player1 = new Player().toDestination();
    const player2 = new Player().toDestination();

    // play one of the samples when they all load
    player1.buffer = soundSamples.get("Music");
    player2.buffer = soundSamples.get("Voice");

    //player1.fadeOut= .10;
    player1.start();
    player2.start();

  });
}
```

I would like to like to send send these two audio files to tone.js channel.

Thanks in advance for any pointers

Comment: it seems this api does what you want: https://tonejs.github.io/docs/14.7.58/Merge

Comment: It does to some extent but again I'd have to have two player objects which needs to be started and stop. I wanted something that could merge into one final channel component.